# My assignment is to make a house using for loops. The house should look like this

Tags: java, printing, geometry

```
    *      
  *****
*********
*********
****  ***
****  ***
```

so far i only have this

```
for (int i=1; i<10; i += 4)
    {

      for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
      {
        System.out.print("*");
      }
      System.out.println("");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What are the assumptions of your code? Are you going to ask the user to input the height and the width of the house? Or are they only required to give 1 side? Or are the sides already given?

Comment: @Michael Because there is many solutions for this  ... Let us know your restrictions such as the number of _for loops_ allowed or other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Andre's answer is the most concise one, but if you want to have *configurable* home building you can use next one(try to change HEIGHT/WIDTH to see effect):

```
public class House {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int HEIGHT = 6;
        final int WIDTH = 9;

        for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT * 2; i += 2) {
            for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++) {// check for roof
                if ((i + (i % 2) + (WIDTH) / 2) < j // right slope
                        || (i + (i % 2) + j) < (WIDTH) / 2)// left slope
                {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                } else {
                    if ((i / 2 >= HEIGHT * 2 / 3) && (j >= WIDTH / 2) && j < WIDTH / 2 + HEIGHT / 3) {// check for door
                        System.out.print(" ");
                    } else {// solid then
                        System.out.print("*");
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

**EDIT** - answer to comment:
Try to run next two example and compare output:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int SIZE = 9;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            System.out.print(i < j ? "+" : "-");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

and

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int SIZE = 9;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            System.out.print(i < SIZE - j - 1 ? "+" : "-");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

First one will give you right slope and second left one. It all come from geometric properties of points. In first case all points will have bigger value on on x axis than on y axis.  In second both x and y in sum won't exceed SIZE.

You can try to modify boolean expression inside of `if()` statement and see what happens, but I'd encourage you to get piece of paper and try to play with paper and pen and see what properties certain points have. Let me know if you need more explanation.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you explain the code a little bit more and how would you approach these types of problems? because I am going encounter many problems like this in the future and I want to make sure I know how to do it.

Comment: I added two more basic samples.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest decision will be:

```
    for (int y = 0; y < 6; y++) {
        int shift = y < 2 ? 4 / (y + 1) : 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < 9 - shift; x++) System.out.print(x >= shift && (y < 4 || (x < 4 || x > 5)) ? "*" : " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a two-dimensional array like this:

```
char matrice [][]= {{' ',' ',' ',' ' '*', ' ',' ',' ',' '},
        {' ',' ','*','*', '*', '*','*',' ',' '}};
```

(And so on). You basically draw your house using your array indexes.

Now you can parse each line using System.out.print() when you have to print a character, and System.out.println("") between each row.

It would look like this:

```
for(char[] line : house){

    for(char d : line){
        System.out.print(d);
    }

    System.out.println("");

}
```

You should take a look at the [for-each statement documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) if you're not familiar with it.